# What is the name for a non-square permutation matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology

Consider a matrix that selects and permutes some but not all of the entries of a vector. That is a binary $n\times m$ matrix, where $n<m$, with a single one per row, for example

$\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\1&0&0\end{bmatrix}$.

Do such matrices have a name? I had a look online and couldn't find anything.

Thanks.

Comment: Exactly what would you like your example matrix to represent? The change $e_1\leftrightarrow e_2$ of basis vectors?

Comment: It is a product of a permutation matrix and a projection matrix, first it swaps round some of the basis vectors and then projects onto the span of some the original basis vectors.

Comment: Well.. I'm not aware any particular name for such.. Call it 'matrix' or 'transformation'. Don't know..

Comment: How about a sub-permutation, or ordered selection matrix?

Comment: Fair enough - for the replies.