# What is name of a matrix which construct from a identity matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In linear algebra, the identity matrix ,$I$, or sometimes ambiguously called a unit matrix, of size $n$ is the $n \times n$ square matrix with ones on the main diagonal and zeros elsewhere, for example

$$I_4=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Let remove the second and fourth columns from $I_4$, a new matrix will be
$$J=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
0&0\\
0&1\\
0&0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

In linear algebra, How can I call the name of the matrix $J$? or how to represent the matrix $J$ in term of the identity matrix $I$. Thank all

Comment: There is no name. $J$ consists of two columns from $I_4$, that's all.

Comment: Is it possible to represent $J$ from $I_{n \times n}$, with removed index are $k,m$

Comment: In MATLAB notations I4(:,[1,3]). Otherwise [duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345166/what-is-the-name-for-a-non-square-permutation-matrix?rq=1)$^T$

Comment: @A.G. I do not need matlab notation. I am considering the linear algebra

Comment: "Partial permutation" sounds like a good name (kind of like a partial isometry). There is no common name that I am aware of, though.

Comment: @user2938494 You asked how one would call it, I gave you one option. MATLAB is also dealing with the linear algebra, in particular, and I have seen MATLAB notations in research papers to address matrix extractions as one possibility.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Maybe just a projection?

Comment: @A.G. That's insufficiently specific

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Permutative projection or $J$-matrix?

Answer (score 1):

A common practice uses the unit vectors $e^{m}_{n}$. For example $e^{m=4}_{n=3}$ is a $0$ vector of length $4$ with the $3$rd element replaced by $1$:
$$
 e^{4}_{3} = 
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
  0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 
\end{array} \right]
$$
In most problems the dimension $m$ is understood. In your case, $m=4$ and the matrix 
$$
 \mathbf{J} = 
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
  e_{1} & e_{3}
\end{array} \right]
$$