# Proper way to represent matrix concatenation with indexed matrix

Tags: matrices, representation-of-algebras

I'm wondering how to properly represent a matrix concatenation equation. Consider a set of matrix with indices such that $X_1, X_2,\dots X_K$, then I would like to create a concatenated matrix $W$ with some $X_k$ whose indices are in a subset of $1,\dots,K$, for example $W = [X_1,X_3,X_5]$. Here we define a set $S = \{1,3,5\}$, can I represent $W$ as $W = [X_k|k \in S]$?

Thanks

Comment: If the concatenated matrix can contain the X_{i}s in a different order than the 1<...<N or some matrices twice, using a set is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\bbR#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\size#1{\operatorname{size}\LR{#1}}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{c}#1\end{array}\right]}
$Let
$$\eqalign{
m,n &= \size{X_k}
,\quad m,Kn = \size{W}
\\
\quad K,\o &= \size{e_k}
,\quad\;\; Kn,n = \size{E_k}
,\quad n,n = \size{I_n}
\\
}$$
where $E_k=(e_k\otimes I_n)$ are block matrix analogs
of the Euclidean basis vectors: $\;e_k\in\bbR{K}$

These matrices allow a concatenated matrix to be written as a sum
$$W = \sum_{k=\o}^K X_kE_k^T \;=\; \m{X_1&X_2&\cdots&X_K}$$
and for the extraction of a constituent matrix from the concatenation
$$X_k = WE_k$$

Your example submatrix can be written in several ways
$$\eqalign{
W_S
 &=\m{X_1&X_3&X_5} \\
 &= W\m{E_1&E_3&E_5} \\
 &= W\Big(\m{e_1&e_3&e_5}\otimes I_n\Big) \\
}$$

**NB:** The symbol $\otimes$ is the Kronecker product and $I_n$ is the identity matrix.

Although they appear quite often in Linear Algebra, there's
[no standard name](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1844691) for matrices like $\m{e_1&e_3&e_5}\:$
although a combination of the adjectives  [semi-orthogonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-orthogonal_matrix) and [logical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_matrix) seems to cover them.